# Can not access shallow from global config

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to use global config for Enzyme in my react app.
I read a few documents about it and thought of giving it a try.
But I must be missing something.

Here is my test script (Grid.test.js) for the **Grid** component. Note that this file is in the same folder of the Componenet file itself. I am not maintaining any separate 'test' folder for the test scripts -

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from './Grid';

test('Grid Renders',()=>{    
const wrapper=shallow(<Grid></Grid>)
expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
})
```

- Jest giving me a warning that that it can't find **shallow**

To create the global configuration, this is the step I followed -

1. Created a folder called 'test' under root folder of the app.
   This folder has a file -'setupTests.js'

Here is the content of the file -

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';;

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

global.React = React;
global.shallow = shallow;
global.render = render;
global.mount = mount;
```

2. Created a jest config file (**jest.config.js**) inside the 'src' folder and this is the content of this file -

   ```
   module.exports = {
       setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/setupTests.js']        
   };
   ```
3. Do I need to make any addition to package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `jest.config.js` file in "src" folder. `<rootDir>` represents "src" folder.

```
module.exports = {
    // Here "<rootDir>" is "src" folder
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/setupTests.js']        
};
```

That's why you are having the problem. You can solve it by

**Solution 1**

Moving the `jest.config.js` file in root level.

So the `<rootDir>` in `setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/setupTests.js']` indicates the root of your app.

**Soution 2**

Moving your `/test/setupTests.js` inside "src" folder.

And add to your script `"test": "jest --config ./src/jest.config.js"`

**Solution 3**

Keeping `/test/setupTests.js` where it is i.e in root level.

Remove `jest.config.js` file.

And add configuration to `package.json`.

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test/setupTests.js"
    ],
  }
```